# Increasing number of nodes for elasticsearch doesn't speed up the queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am pretty new to Elasticsearch.

Right know I have pretty expensive search query, it uses nested querying, highlighting, fuzziness and so on. But right now I can't changed that.

So I decided I will try to upgrade my cluster, previously it had 3 nodes, 16GB, 0.5CPU each.

Now I upgraded it to 6 nodes, 16GB, 3CPU each.

I was hoping for some speedup on queries however I did not get it. For some reasons it started to be even slower. For example queries which took 12 seconds now last about 17 seconds.

Is there anything more I have to do after upgrading number of nodes. Because after reading some docs I though it's all automatic.

I will put result of `/_nodes` query maybe it will give some more insight. I have to use external service to share json because of char limit

https://wtools.io/paste-code/bFUC

Comment: Have you looked at [this page of documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html) ?

Comment: what does the query look like? and the mapping? have you done an `explain` on the query?